# The Next Badge does not show hint on mobile view

Tags: feature-request

On my mobile the Next Badge does not show any hint. I always have to switch to the desktop view in order to get a hint on how to acquire the Next Badge.

Below is the screenshot for mobile view. If you tap on the Newest Badge it shows you details but when you tap on the Next Badge it doesn't react.

[image]

Below is the desktop view which shows much better description on how to get the Next Badge.

[image]

Comment: Can you enlarge screenshots, we don't see very well

Comment: @Mistalis FTFY ;)